# Programatically change screen orientation in Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a Cordova project. Does anybody know how to change screen orientation programmatically in Windows Phone 8 platform for Cordova? What I really want is programmatically invoke landscape keyboard, for that I think orientation change is also required.

Is it possible via Cordova plugin implementation? Can somebody provide a basic walkthrough layout for attaining this?

Note: Cordova Plugin registry doesn't have any windows phone 8 plugin for changing screen orientation.

Comment: atlast i created a custom plugin for this! i will post it as soon as i get time! Currently a lil busy!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.To change screen Orientation

// Portrait Orientation

```
    SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait;
```

// Landscape Orientation

```
    SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
```

// For Lanscape and Portrait

```
   SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.PortraitOrLandscape;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Currently iam using portrait orientation and i can call a C# function from javascript, and when i call that function i want to programatically change screen orientation to landscapeng. What should i write in this c Sharp function?